# c# regex I cannot remove two lines from text because of the spacing

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I am trying to remove one of the lines from an xml but I cannot remove it because of the spacing, I guess. Can anybody help me with REGEX? I am not very expert on it.

here is my xml lines that I want to remove...

```
  <otv_ek44_Bildirimi>
<otv_ek44_Bildirimi>
```

I want to remove one these two lines from xml regardless of any spacing before,middle or after. How can I do that?

here is my poor code.

```
string s2 = @"      <otv_ek44_Bildirimi>
    <otv_ek44_Bildirimi>";
fileContents = Regex.Replace(fileContents, s2, "");
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a regex, you appear to be doing a direct string replace. Have you considered `String.Replace`? ***BUT*** it is far better to manipulate XML with an XML Parser/API (.NET has four) because XML is not "regular" (in the formal sense) so quite likely using a regex will just makes things worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use Regex, try replacing the spaces in your `s2` regular expression with `\s+` (=match for more than one whitespace character - space, tab, etc.).

```
string s2 = @"\s+<otv_ek44_Bildirimi>
\s+<otv_ek44_Bildirimi>";
```

I would strongly suggest using `string.Replace(old, new)` in this case.

Furthermore, I suggest to not modify XML or any structured data with string manipulation or Regex. You could use an XML parser, or use [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) to run jQuery(CSS)-like queries on your XML and manipulate it that way.

Comment: it doesnt replace it because I am not sure how many spaces there are

Comment: I agree with you but I have to do it this way and I dont have much time.

Comment: @ayilmaz I updated my answer to give an example of the regexp you should be using. But please, if you have any other choice, please **do not** use regex to modify/parse XML.